# Seemingly wrong eigenvectors for numerical matrix whose elements differ in scale by orders of magnitude

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I stumbled upon an issue with computing eigenvalues of a matrix which I discovered while debugging some code which uses reconstructing the matrix from its eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

First of all, here is the (anti-hermitian) matrix in question:

```
mat=Uncompress["1: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"];
```

You will notice, that the elements of `mat` differ in magnitude by six orders of magnitude. We compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors

```
{eigVals, eigVecs} = Eigensystem[mat];
```

and inspect what they look like:

```
Chop[eigVals, 10^-7]//Column
```

Now, we make a sanity check:

```
Chop[eigVecs.mat.ConjugateTranspose[eigVecs], 10^-7]//MatrixForm
```

and observe that there are off-diagonal elements which can get close to 100 in magnitude. This should definitely not be the case. It also appears that the eigenvectors are not orthonormalized properly, although they should according to the [documentation of `Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) where it says:

> For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized.

```
Chop[eigVecs.eigVecs\[ConjugateTranspose], 10^-7] // MatrixForm
```

reveals that there are off-diagonal elements ~0.25.

I am aware that the huge difference in scales does not render this an easy task, though I need to understand what is going wrong here and find a workaround. Can anyone give me some insight/fix/explanation?

Comment: Did you try to take the MatrixLog of your matrix (which I obviously cannot access), and to diagonalize it? The set of normalized eigenvectors of MatrixLog[mat] should coincide with those of mat.

Comment: @marmot No, haven't tried that but I will. Thanks for the suggestion. But why can't you access the matrix? `mat` should be accessible via the `Uncompress` line at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know what Uncompress does. The MatrixLog tricks appears to work.

Comment: Lukas, I suspect that you may be suffering from loss of precision in your numerical calculations. Consider for instance setting the precision of your `mat` higher and repeating your calculations: `{eigVals, eigVecs} = Eigensystem[SetPrecision[mat, 30]]; Chop[eigVecs.ConjugateTranspose[eigVecs] == IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]]` returns `True`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for this suggestion. In fact, the original problem comes from a Matlab simulation and I believe there is nothing like SetPrecision there. But glad to see it is such a simple fix in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible workaround is based on MatrixLog

```
mat = Uncompress[
   "1:eJxTTMoPShNiYGAoZgESPpnFJWg8JhCPHUg45+cW5KRWFDFAAZwxGJT8y70gF+/\
F7IBHic3fJV9OcxzfPxicSzclKprPnolK/\
MXnaVNIuNgPBufClVAxDR4u7N6WuqeT9vFuSjiBEREd9A9rWiuxIZzAiMi+9PcRfcvB18fT1pm4/\
6Awaey7or17Ff6ALM+4bbF7pJWD1FFC/9J00NXF5+5drlxbhTeZNhBOYMuj9dfViY+\
wcpA6SuhfmhKbBqnTBqNOCfZqlui+\
ObFGBwdDjI0qobw0JTYNUqcNRrcSbKG678HRZDpEStNBVxfTTQl12qbUUUKdWoaI7AstBIZtv3j4KSGibUod\
i6hTy5QTTmBENIboHwGjaZAapSnHgeHT06d/aTqaBmmuJDZYVuRjAt5kOph6+\
vQvTUduGhxMPf2LTzuc5g2rLhQppenITYNDrKffUXTAdQglU1JKU2LT4FCdixxM7R5aKxlM46ak1DLEpsGhO\
hc5mNo9g0AJ3cZNSall6FsXj5amg99H1GmbktJOpm8aHC1NB7+\
PiFBCRNuUlHYyfdMgdZSMlqaDv6cPaZs6EVWaDsU0OFqaDouevlvixv2gZAoAconf8g=="];

lmat = MatrixLog[mat];
ev = Orthogonalize[Eigenvectors[lmat]];
Chop[ev.mat.ConjugateTranspose[ev], 10^-7] // MatrixForm
Chop[ev.ConjugateTranspose[ev]] // MatrixForm
```